# How do I dynamically choose the view form

Tags: sharepoint-online, formula

I've got a SharePoint Online list that I want to use as a ticketing system.  Users can submit a few different types of tickets.  The various ticket types contain different fields, validation, etc. All items will post to the same SharePoint list, and I will be using personal views to control which data is displayed.

When I click on an item to view it, I need it to first read the "Ticket Type" text column of the selected list item, and then direct the user to the correct form to display that type of item, and then display the item.

My biggest struggle here is in reading the Ticket Type column from the currently selected list item.  Totally unsure how to do this and everything I've found online so far has not worked, and has given various errors with every attempt.

I want to do something like this in the OnView of the SharepointIntegration:

```
    If(Ticket Type = "Account Issue",
    Navigate(AcctIssueView);ViewForm(frmAcctIssueView),
    Navigate(HomeScreen))
```

But it gives me a bunch of errors on Ticket Type = "Account Issue".

Can anyone correct my approach, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can take a look at [SharePoint content types](https://sharegate.com/blog/sharepoint-content-types-understand-use-create), if not done already. Using this feature you can save data from multiple type of tickets in same list and SharePoint will automatically open the form with the details that you would need for that ticket.

Please let me know if this does not help or I understood it differently than you need.

Comment: This is perfect, my friend!  Exactly the concept I was missing.  Many thanks!

Comment: As a follow up, it turns out that Content Type is technically available in PowerApps for logic, however Microsoft admits it is a bug that the Name property is not accessible.  Saw posts about this issue from early last year, so it doesn't seem to be high on the list to be corrected. Back to doing something like my original post, but this time I just set a text field with a hardcoded value at the time the form is submitted. That way I can read from the text field and perform my logic that way.